# When java app run inside Docker Container, IDE cannot find classes, how to connect them together?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea

When my app is running inside a docker container, the problem is the integration between the environment inside the container and outside the container means my IDE does not know what classes are defined and all the gradle packages that I think my java app is setting in the class path are not available for my IDE (IntelliJ in this case).

Is there a solution to this, that would allow me to properly work in Docker, yet have some IDE integration for autocomplete and associated functionality?

Comment: Only if you run IDE inside the VM and connect to it via the Gateway. https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/.

Comment: hmm, unfortunate that I can't configure java and intellij to put all the gradle stuff into the project folder, which when mounted for development could be used to resolve this information locally and inside the container

Comment: You can have a local copy of the project on your system and deploy it to Docker for testing, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-java-app-in-a-container.html.

Comment: I would always have a local copy of the project on the computer, but the container is where it's being run, and gradle is executing, so the issue is, how to have both working at the same time. I found some option that lets me configure gradle to define the class path. I was thinking to put that into the project directory. Then tell IntelliJ to use that same directory for the classpath

Comment: Gradle sets the classpath for your project. It should work locally. If it doesn't work, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).